# "given version requirement is invalid" while downloading dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Following [this example](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/Piston-Tutorials/tree/master/getting-started):

```
$ cargo build --verbose
Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
failed to parse registry's information for: wayland-client

Caused by:
the given version requirement is invalid
```

This happens on every example and builds from other repos. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I installed Cargo and Rustc through apt.  Using versions:  rustc 1.7.0 and cargo 0.8.0.

My Cargo.toml from the example:

```
[package]

name = "spinning-square"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [
    "TyOverby <ty@pre-alpha.com>",
    "Nikita Pekin <contact@nikitapek.in>"
]

[[bin]]
name = "spinning-square"

[dependencies]
piston = "0.31.1"
piston2d-graphics = "0.21.1"
pistoncore-glutin_window = "0.35.0"
piston2d-opengl_graphics = "0.40.0"
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `rustc -V` and `cargo -V` print?

Comment: I added the versions of cargo and rustc.  Also I included the Cargo.toml from the example I'm having issues with.

Comment: You may want to upgrade rustc (and cargo). Version 1.15.0 was released last week, which is clearly twice as mature as 1.7.0 going by the numbers :) There's been lot of polish since 1.7.0, notably much clearer error messages, increased stable APIs, ... I advise you to use `rustup` to get 1.15.0, really.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using

```
$ sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
```

and then it started to work.  However, I do not know if this is the true solution because I removed libsdl2 and it continued to work after that.  A theory of mine is that because Piston uses sdl2, it corrected something to make it work, maybe.

If anyone has found a better solution for the next guy to have issues, I'll leave this post unanswered for a while longer.

Comment: It is wise to keep this answer unaccepted. Piston does not strictly depend on SDL 2, and it should not be needed at all for the dependencies that you have mentioned.